# How to create filter for options value using ajax in php and zf2

Tags: php, ajax, filter

How to make filter using ajax i want to get single option value for each selection and when click on filter button it sends data  to getproductlistcb controller.
please help
HTML CODE is-

```
<div class="filter-category">
                  <form>
                     <input type="submit" value="filter" class="btn filter-btn">                     
                     <div class="user-category-select">  
                     <select required=""  name="sort" form="filter-form" class="btn filter-form-select" >
                        <option value="" disabled="">Sort</option>
                        <option value="popularity" selected="">Most Popular</option>
                        <option value="highest-rated">Highest Rated</option>
                        <option value="newest">Newest</option>
                        <option id="aesc" value="price-low-to-high">Lowest Price</option>
                        <option id="desc" value="price-high-to-low">Highest Price</option>                      
                     </select>
                    <label class="filter-category-select"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
                      </div>
                  </form>
               </div>
```

AjaX-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.btn filter-form-select').on('change',function(){
  var data=$('#search_form');
       
     $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "<?php echo $this->url('page', array('controller' => 'page', 'action' => 'getproductlistcb')); ?>",
           data:data,
            success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
        alert(data);
                $("#").html(data);
            }
        });
  });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `:option` in selector? For example, in that way: `$('select.filter-form-select option:selected').val();`?

I think you are looking for DOM-selector like that:
`$('.filter-form-select option:selected')`.

So, in your case, in your code the code below might be helpful:

```
var $formData = $('#search_form');
var $formFilters = $formData.find('select.filter-form-select');
var $firstFilter = $formFilters.first();
var $option = $firstFilter.find('option:selected');
var optionText = $option.length ? $option.text() : null;
var optionValue = $option.length ? $option.val() : null;
```

Be aware, that `$formFilters` is not just one element, it's jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements.

An additional way, try to debug and check what you have in your this-context and event:

```
$('.btn filter-form-select').on('change',function(event) {
  console.log('clicked: ' + event.target.nodeName);
  console.log('Context: ' + this);
});
```

I hope, something from that will help you a bit.